# Is there a method to insert a value from a JavaScript variable into the embedded Excel sheet?

Tags: excel, google-chrome-extension, embed, sharepoint-online, excel-online

I have tried to build a simple Chrome extension where, upon the user pressing a button on the popup window, the distance between two loacation using google map is extracted and inserted into an embedded Excel file cell. However, I cannot insert a value into the embedded Excel sheet using JavaScript.

Initially, I tried using the mouse and keyboard events to copy-paste to the Excel sheet, but it did not work. Even though the mouse and keyboard events work manually, JavaScript keyboard events do not. Then I found this article [text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh315812(v=office.14)), but the JavaScript dialog box for sharing the embed option is not available for my Excel sheet.How can I handle an embedded Excel sheet using JavaScript?[Java script missing on dialogbox image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYYnR.png)

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "PML Copy paste",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Extract information ",
  "action": {
    "default_popup" : "hello.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab","scripting"]
}
```

hello.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PML Cal</title>
    <style>
        /* Button Style */
        .button {
          display: inline-block;
          padding: 10px 20px;
          font-size: 16px;
          font-weight: bold;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          text-decoration: none;
          color: #ffffff;
          background-color: #4CAF50;
          border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
          border-radius: 25px;
          transition: all 0.3s ease;
        }

        .button:hover {
          background-color: #45a049;
          border-color: #45a049;
        }

        /* Optional: Add more styles to make it more attractive */
        .button:active {
          transform: translateY(2px);
        }

        .button:focus {
          outline: none;
        }

        /* Optional: Add responsiveness */
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
          .button {
            font-size: 14px;
            padding: 8px 16px;
          }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>PML Price Calculator</h1>
    <!-- Button HTML -->
    <div><a href="#"  class="button" id="CatchDistance">Catch Distance</a></div>
    <div style="margin: 20px;">

    </div>
    <iframe  width="1500" height="650" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://dimogroup.sharepoint.com/teams/PickMyLoadCostCalculator/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc={4d0d4740-bb58-464f-9a17-d34af1e7ed66}&action=embedview&wdAllowInteractivity=False&AllowTyping=True&ActiveCell='CAL'!S14&Item=i_pml&wdInConfigurator=True&wdInConfigurator=True"></iframe>
    <script src="CatchDistance.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

CatchDistance.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var extractButton = document.getElementById('CatchDistance');
  extractButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: {tabId: tabs[0].id},
        function: function() {
          var elementValue = document.querySelector("#section-directions-trip-0 > div.MespJc > div > div.XdKEzd > div.ivN21e.tUEI8e.fontBodyMedium > div").textContent;
          return elementValue;
        }
      }, function(results) {
        alert(results[0].result);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Try the deprecated document.execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).